# Discord.py ctx commands not recognised

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

im fairly new to coding in general and recently started trying to code my own bot. Almost all of the tutorials i have seen use the ctx command however, whenever i use it i get this error:

```
 "NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined"
```

Here is part of my code that uses the ctx command. The aim is to get it to delete the last 3 messages sent.

```
    @client.event
async def purge(ctx):
    """clear 3 messages from current channel"""
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await channel.purge(limit=3, check=None, before=None)
    return True



@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("purge"):
        await purge(ctx)



client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

Full error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 31, in on_message
    await purge(ctx)
NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined
```

I'm hosting the server on repl.it if that makes any difference and as i said, im pretty new to coding so it's possible i have missed something very obvious, any help is appreciated. ^_^

Comment: If you observe properly, `ctx` variable is not declared in the `on_message()` funtion but you are trying to use it to call the `purge()` function.

Comment: Also, if I remember correctly you cannot even use `ctx` with `on_message()` like this `on_message(ctx)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix to that is:

```
async def purge(message):
    await message.delete()
    channel = message.channel
    await channel.purge(limit=3)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("purge"):
        await purge(message)
```

The problem is the `on_message` function uses `message` and not `ctx`. Replacing message with `ctx` wont work because im pretty sure the `on_message` cant use `ctx`